# When creating or editing a CiviRule, not all custom fields are available in Condition Parameters

Tags: activities, civirules

Civi 4.6.9
Drupal 7.44
CiviRule 1.2

I am trying to build a CiviRule that creates a scheduled activity based on a custom field used for activities.

All looks to be good until I get to the CiviRules Edit Condition parameters form.
I select Activity for entity. When I go to fields, I see most custom fields that were created but the list is not complete. It appears to get cut off.

The fields are listed in the order they were created. In our case, the list cuts off between custom field sets 92 and 93 and displays 154 fields.

Of course I need the ones further down!

Any guidance?

Comment: was this simply that the dropdown was only showing 25, which is the limit set for hte dropdowns iirc, and is what is causing me issues on a Memb Type 'action' as we are not seeing Types we need (and yes i will just alter it in the db)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to file an issue on the Github page, and hope for technical guidance on how to solve it there.

However, I could think of a hack...

You could take one custom field before 92 that you are not using (or not using for CiviRules), and swap the id directly in the SQL-database. In that way you will probably see your custom field in the list.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. GitHub issues reported [here](https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.civirules/issues/93).